# Change Unordered list item's color on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can we change an unordered list's item color when it is focused with tab or clicked with mouse using CSS ?

Edit:
Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngLrB/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .form li input:focus
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Check that...

If your interested, this jQuery may work, please someone step in and correct it if its wrong!

```
$(".form li input").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("li").css("background-color","yellow");
});

$(".form li input").blur(function(){
        $(this).closest("li").css("background-color","white");
});
```

Comment: Check my JSFiddle, I edited the post. I want it to change color when focused

Comment: I want to change the color of the surrounding list item and not the control itself. Since many grouped controls would lie in the same <li>

Comment: Well im afraid you may have to use jQuery/javascript if you want to do that...i'm pretty sure you cant do it with pure CSS

Comment: Thanks Ben. I will change the tags of question.

Comment: Hi Ben, looking at the code I am sure it is the right approach. But maybe because of some syntax I cant get it to work. I am using JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ngLrB/

Comment: Are you ok inserting this jQuery? Have you used jQuery before?

Comment: Thanks Ben,you're the man !=) it is working now. Is there a way to do the same function on click of the list item. I tried doing the same event for click/blur of li but it won't work as expected.

Comment: $(".form li").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
});

$(".form li").blur(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","white");
});

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible with focussed list-items, because I guess it's not intended to be focussed. One thing you could do is to change the color on mouseover:

```
li:hover { color: #F00; background-color: #0F0; }
```

Comment: Check my JSFiddle, I edited the post. I want it to change color when focused

Comment: I have seen it done any idea on how they do this focus thing with list items ? Somebody posted a good reply and deleted it. It said something to do with a div or span.

Answer (score 0):

IF so try to use glowing tab .. which is newest and fastest technique to change hover tab.. IT will take position as argument. on hover event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your pure CSS solution http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/a93Rb/, only compatible with FF for now. You can make it compatible for the remaining browsers.

Comment: How is that anything like what the O/P asked for??

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
// catch a click on any of the <li> items
$('li').click(function(){
// store a reference to the specific <li> that
// was clicked.
var $li = $(this);

// toggle the class (if it's applied, it's removed.
// if it's removed, re-apply it)
$li.toggleClass('highlight');

// Remove below code so that on click the highlight will be fixed
// Now, if it's applied, remove the class from any
// other <li> (single item clicked at a time)
if ($li.hasClass('highlight')){
    $li.siblings().removeClass('highlight');
}
});
});
```